# Troubleshooting "Hard Drive Not Installed"

Tags: ssd, motherboard, troubleshooting, pci-express, m.2

I have a Dell XPS 13 laptop that has stopped recognizing the hard drive.

The hard drive is a SK Hynix 256 GB SSD (PCIe NVMe M.2) [1].

I have having an extremely difficult time determining whether the problem is the SSD or the motherboard. It seems there are no adapters on the market for reading M.2 PCIe NVMe SSDs so I can't use that to determine if the SSD is at fault. I have no other computers that can take PCIe NVMe M.2 style SSDs.

I am hesitant to buy a brand new one if the problem is the motherboard.

Any tips?

[1] [https://www.amazon.com/SK-Hynix-256GB-Solid-State/dp/B075QMZ1LC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075QMZ1LC)

Comment: I don't see how you can troubleshoot this without either another device that supports NVMe drive or another drive... Seeings as how you can get a replacement NVMe drive from multiple outlets for less than the price of a "shop fee" at a local PC repair place, seems like the next course of action is set for you.

Comment: That's what I feared...